# CakePHP paginate order not working for SELECT .. AS .. fields

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

CakePHP 2.x

I'm having problems sorting paginated data that contains database fields that generate SELECT .. AS statements.

Trying to order on the alias of the selected fields automatically translates to the original field name, making it impossible to sort on SUM() fields etc.

Code:

```
[...]
$paginate['fields'] = array('SUM(Item.count) AS count');
$paginate['order'] = array('count' => 'DESC');
[...]
```

SQL generated:

```
SELECT Item.count AS count FROM items ORDER BY Item.count
```

What I was expecting:

```
SELECT Item.count AS count FROM items ORDER BY count
```

Any help to work around this is very welcome.

Comment: why not using virtual fields? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

Comment: @mark I'm new to CakePHP and didn't know / think about this -- thanks, will try right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case I would use virtual fields:

```
$this->Item->virtualFields['count'] = 'SUM(Item.count)';
```

Either in the controller prior to the paginate() call or set via model itself.

But aren't you missing a group statement then?

Comment: virtualFields was indeed a perfect solution and also gave me much cleaner code in the end.  The group statement I purposly left out of my example, but I am indeed using a group.